# In an WinRT / Universal app how do I check for a change in the image source

Tags: c#, if-statement, win-universal-app

How do I create an if statement which checks the image source. Here is my code:

```
public void WhoWon()
{
    if (UserPick.Source ="ms-appx:Assets/RPS3.png")
    {
    }      
}
```

The error says

> cannot implicitly  convert from string to wundows.ui.blahblah.media.change..

Two questions:

1. How do I fix this exception?
2. How do I do check if the imagesource changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be able to know when the image source has changed by subscribing to the [Image.ImageOpened Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imageopened.aspx).
2. Comparing for equality takes two equal signs, not one which assigns a value

   `if (UserPick.Source == "ms-appx:Assets/RPS3.png")`